BDD Feature Files structure guidelines
Continuing on from BDD Feature Files guidelines
Say I have 10 feature files testing user actions 1-10, 1-Fund transferring, 2-Display balance, 3-etc
feature files:
In 'Fund transferring', login, navigate to fund transfers, and transfer test.
In 'Display balance', login, navigate to balances, and verify balances.
What is the best way to structure these to have login as a pre-requisite so as not to need logging in each time?
In 'login', login successfully. If passed:

In 'Fund transferring', navigate to fund transfers, transfer test.

In 'Display balance', navigate to balances, and verify balances.


etc
